# Clustered standard errors using tbl_uvregression

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, logistic-regression, gtsummary, gt

Within the gtsummary package, is there any way to add in clustered standard errors to the following example logistic regression?

```
library(gtsummary)

df <-data.frame(cluster = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                y=c(0,0,1,1,1),
                x1=c(10,20,30,40,50),
                x2=c(0,1,0,1,1))

x<-
  tbl_uvregression(
    df[c("x1", "x2", "y", "cluster")],
    glm,
    y = y,
    method.args = list(family = binomial),
    include = -cluster,
    exponentiate = TRUE)
```

Comment: what do you mean by add in? add in to the model or add in to the table output?

Comment: You can check out the documentation for the tidy_robust() function from gtsummary

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added the following line to the above code:
`tidy_fun = partial(tidy_robust, vcov="CR", vcov_args=list(type = "CR1", cluster=cluster))`

However, I get a warning message:
 `The vcov and vcov_args are not available with method = "profile"`